# PHP undefined function error in php 5.6, but not 5.5 or 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.5, php-5.6

I have the following PHP code for connecting to an SQL database:

```
$host="localhost"; 
$username="username"; 
$password="pw;";
$db_name="name_of_db";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

which runs fine on two Linux boxes I have running PHP 5.4.45 and PHP 5.5.9. However, when I run the same thing on a box running PHP 5.6.24, it throws the error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in <filename>`.

When I looked in the PHP manual at backwards incompatible differences between 5.5 and 5.6 I couldn't see anything that would have an effect on this. ([link](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration56.incompatible.php))

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to disable the mysql API in PHP 5.6 and that appears to be the case here. Probably a pro active way to ensure no obsolete code is being used/written

Comment: I think it's been recommended to use mysqli rather than mysql for quite a while.

Comment: You could ask whoever installed this PHP why they chose (legitimately) to nuke out the `mysql_` functions from their build.

Comment: Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @PeterStock ... that is if you intend to continue forever with a MySQL database. If you want to keep your options , use PDO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it works on one and not the other, it's gotta be settings.

Run this:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

If you don't see MySQL extension listed, you should add it to the `php.ini` file: `extension=php_mysql.dll`

Now, you shouldn't use the `mysql_` extensions. They are deprecated and not available at all in 7. My suggestion is to use something like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: please dont encourage people to use `mysql_`, a high security risk. There is a good reason why they have been **removed** from php7 and deprecated in earlier reasons.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, please read the answer entirely before making these statements below. "Now, you shouldn't use the mysql_ extensions. They are deprecated and not available at all in 7. My suggestion is to use something like PDO". While I do **NOT** encourage anyway to use deprecated extensions (as I stated above), the question wasn't about which extensions or tools to use.

Answer (score 0):

The best information you can get, is to look directly to php manual to exactly this function.
[`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

There you can read, that from 5.5.0 is deprecated.

Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) connection instead - [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)
with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

This is the modern approach.

Answer (score 0):

For the version 5.6.x and above php suggests using mysqli instead of mysql. 
In light of that it throws a depreciation notice.

If you open this link up you can see : [php mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)